# Making all hyperlink in div visible

Tags: html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab-nav-wrapper-report li.active").click();
    $($(".tab-nav-wrapper-report li.active a").attr("href")).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-controls-report mt-4">
  <div class="tab-nav-wrapper-report">
    <ul>
      <li class="active" data-id="1">
        <a href="#2_1">Test3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#3_1" data-id="1">Test4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content-wrapper-report">
    <div id="2_1" class="tab-content" style="display:none;">
      //Something in here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper-report">
  <ul>
    <li class="active" data-id="2">
      <a href="#2_2">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#3_2" data-id="2">Test2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-wrapper-report">
  <div id="2_2" class="tab-content" style="display:none;">
    //Something in here
  </div>
  <div id="3_2" class="tab-content" style="display:none;">
    //Something in here
  </div>
</div>
```

By this code, only the first  ".tab-nav-wrapper-report li.active a" would be shown and the second would not be affected

How can I make all of the ".tab-nav-wrapper-report li.active a" would be shown all together?

Comment: it should be `$($(".tab-nav-wrapper-report li a").attr("href")).show();`

Comment: @sathyareddy: I just want the active li  attr href be visible, not all of them